# Erase line drawn in canvas element with vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to implement an eraser functionality in my canvas, I'm able to draw with this function:

```
canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
context = canvas.getContext("2d")

function reposition(event) {
coords.x = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
coords.y = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
context.arc
}

function draw(event) {
context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth = "30";
context.lineCap = "square";
context.strokeStyle = "#999999"
context.moveTo(coords.x, coords.y);
reposition(event);
context.lineTo(coords.x, coords.y);
context.stroke();
}
```

Can I alter this in a way where instead of drawing a coloured stroke, it will erase the canvas to make the line drawn transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thing that worked here was adding `GlobalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';` to my function

Final function:

````
function draw(event) {
context.beginPath();
GlobalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';'
context.lineWidth = "30";
context.lineCap = "square";
context.strokeStyle = "#999999"
context.moveTo(coords.x, coords.y);
reposition(event);
context.lineTo(coords.x, coords.y);
context.stroke();
}```
````